# Who told Toko that she was adopted?

Tags: maria-sama-ga-miteru

In the 4th season of *Maria Watches Over Us*, it's revealed that Toko was adopted. In the final episode, when she and Yumi went on the half-day date reward which Toko won for finding Yumi's Card, Toko reveals that her real parents died in a car crash which she was the sole survivor of, and she was later adopted by the daughter of the head doctor of the hospital, who happened to be a classmate and friend of Toko's biological mother.

Toko tells Yumi that she had suspected for a while that she was adopted from overhearing "cruel adults". However, it has only been confirmed recently in a couple of episodes earlier. During the scene where Suguru Kashiwagi is driving Toko, he gets angry that Toko has found out and starts questioning her who opened their mouth, naming 3 women (I can't remember their names, but I believe they were the ones who tried to shame Yumi during the 3rd OVA Season). However, Toko doesn't answer, being more scared of Suguru's aggressive speeding.

So I am wondering, is it known who told Toko she was adopted, or did she found out herself?

Answer (score 1):

Nobody ever told Toko directly that she was adopted. As you mentioned, she overheard her relatives speaking about it, and she confirmed it by looking it up in a registry.

Quoting a line from [Toko](http://marimite.wikia.com/wiki/T%C5%8Dko_Matsudaira#Background)'s article on wikia:

> She found out the truth later after listening in to some of her relatives' conversations, and confirming it in a registry

So Suguru just got angry and there was no specific person who revealed the secret